# Weird Pointer function in reference to USB Host Library for Arduino

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, arduino, usb

I am working with an [Arduino library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) and have a question as to a certain call it makes. This question pertains to the BTD (Bluetooth device library)

In the header file under the protected variables it creates a pointer:

```
  USB *pUsb;
```

In the cpp:

```
BTD::BTD(USB *p){
  connectToWii(false),
  pairWithWii(false),
  connectToHIDDevice(false),
  pairWithHIDDevice(false),
  pUsb(p), // Pointer to USB class instance - mandatory
  /*
   *Other unrelated Code
  */
}
```

I simply would like to know what the calling of pUsb(p) does.
I apologize for any issues with my question as this is my first submission to this website, and I am fairly new to C++. I do know java, so I understand coding concepts, but I've never seen this before and after an hour and a half of researching found nothing helpful. Thanks for the help!
KPitt

Answer (score 0):

You did not copy the syntax correctly, it would actually be

```
BTD::BTD(USB *p)
: connectToWii(false),
  pairWithWii(false),
  connectToHIDDevice(false),
  pairWithHIDDevice(false),
  pUsb(p) // Pointer to USB class instance - mandatory
{
  /*
   *Other unrelated Code
  */
}
```

Note the `:` before the constructor body. This is the [constructor member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), it is initializing the member variables of that class. Therefore this line

```
pUsb(p)
```

Is taking the `USB*` argument `p` and copying it to the member variable `pUsb`. Long story short, it is just copying a pointer to its member variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that might be what it was but couldn't find anything to support it, sorry for the syntax error as well.